# Make bootstrapper prerequisite to not install under 64bits

Tags: setup-project, bootstrapping, bootstrapper

i have a setup project that installs a couple of prerequisites, some with the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator (Framework, SQLExpress, a video codec) but my setup project it's only for 32bits. I have a check over that and the msi displays an error if the SO is 64bits, but the prerequisites install anyway if the SO is 64bits.. this is the first problem i have to deal, but the other problem without naming the first one is that if the SO is 64bits, then the prerequisite installation of the SQL Express gives an error because the SQL Express is for 32bits and i dont want to display that message.
So.. how can i make a way to prevent the prerequisites to install if the SO is 64bits?

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will need to create a custom bootstrapper for your prerequisites.

http://jcrawfor74.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/bootstrap-manifest-generator-2008-how-to-guide-v2/

Then you will need to specify install conditions to exclude x64. The raw XML looks like this:

```
<FailIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture"
        Compare="ValueEqualTo"
        Value="IA64"
        String="InvalidPlatformArchitect" />
```

Comment: Wow! Looks like what I want! I will try it. Thanks! One more thing... a custom bootstrapper needs something to install, but this is not something to install but is something to check. It will work anyway?